# Elastic exact matching and substring matching together

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I know that Elastic have  "keyword" type in order to find something with exact matching. Ex:

```
"address":  { "type": "keyword"}
```

**That's cool. exact matching works!**

but I would like to have **both** "**exact matching**" and "**sub-string**" matching. So I decided to create the following mapping:

```
   "address":  { "type": "text" , "index": true }
```

**Problem**
If I have "text" type, how can I search exact matching string? (not sub-string). I've tried several ways but does not works:

```
GET testing_index/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : { 
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { 
                    "address" :  "washington"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
GET testing_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "address" : "washington"
    }
  }
}
```

I need just something universal mapping:

- to find exact string
- to find sub-strings

I hope elastic can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, text fields use the [default analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), which drops most punctuation, breaks up text into individual words, and lower cases them. For instance, the standard analyzer would turn the string “Quick Brown Fox!” into the terms [`quick`, `brown`, `fox`]. As you can imagine, this makes it difficult to write an exact match query against the text field. For your use case, I suggest one of 2 options:

1. store as `keyword`, and accomplish sub-string-like matching using [wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) or [fuzzy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) queries. Wildcard queries, in particular queries with a leading wildcard, are notoriously slow, so proceed with caution.
2. store the field twice: one as `keyword` and one as `text`. Obvious downside here is bloating the size of the index.

For more background, see the "Term Query" Elasticsearch documentation, and in particular the section on "Why doesn’t the term query match my document?": https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Comment: just fast question: can I use wildcard , fuzzy  and regexp with text type data? I mean if regexp works for both with keyword and text how to choose which one is useful for me?

Comment: You can only use wildcards on fields that are not analyzed. regexp works on text, but keep in mind, Elasticsearch will apply the regexp to the terms produced by the tokenizer for that field, and not to the original text of the field. This is often not what you want

Comment: That's good answer. so regexp works both keyword and text but in text it searches with tokens.

Comment: Additional question: for performance reason, regexp with keyword looks like much faster? and memory efficient? I just nee simple "contains" regex   (.*text.*), so maybe keyword is the best option.

Comment: Both wildcard and regex are equally slow. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_wildcard_and_regexp_queries.html

Comment: Also keep in mind, if you're looking for "text" and it's a single, whole word (one of your tokens) that's the fastest query there is. That's what elasticsearch is good at